# How to assignTo a setter in Salesforce that requires an index parameter, such as a List<>?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

In a controller I have two values:

```
public List<String> StringValue {get; set;} 
public List<String> ListValue {get; set;}
```

The ListValue is initialized in the constructor and several strings are added. At this point in a value I can refer to these with {!StringValue} and {!ListValue[1]} in a VisualForce page. The list one in particular is the focus - I can even add pseudo-constants (getters) as indexes, making {!ListValue[nameIndex]} a valid reference.

However I've run into an exception when trying to *set* a list value instead of a simple string value.

```
<apex:param value="123" assignTo="{!ListValue[1]}" />
```

The exception is `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to common.formula.FormulaFieldReference`

I think I understand the basics of the problem - Salesforce can't create a setter reference that includes an index parameter (meaning only setters that take a single parameter can be referenced).

Is there any way around this, or do I just have to create a massive amount of ListValue1, ListValue2 variables and associated code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hack, but it avoids you having to create dozens of variables.

```
<apex:param value="1:123" assignTo="{!smartAssigner}" />
```

Then in your controller:

```
public void setSmartAssigner(String myval) { // parse the colon, set list value appropriately.
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across a way to do this in the style you're requesting, I'd suggest that to get this going the easiest thing to do would be to concatenate the values you want into one parameter and then split them back up inside the controller.

You might find a suitable way to do this with `<apex:repeat>` but I'm not sure on your full use case.